# Using srand() within a function

Tags: c, srand

I am learning how to use "rand()" and "srand()" in C. In the book that I am reading, it asks to modify a program that generates random numbers so that the user supplies a seed. This ensures the numbers are random. I am able to generate new numbers using the basic code directly below, but it will not work when I try to use it within the program beneath it.

```
int main() 
{
    int seed;

    srand(seed);

    printf("Please enter a seed: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);

    printf("The random number is: %d\n", rand());

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here is the program I am having trouble getting "srand() to work in below. I have tried asking the user for the seed in "main", rather than the prn_random_numbers function and everything else I could think of. It still only behaves like "rand()" and spits out the same number regardless of the seed that I enter. What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, the book doesn't give any answers to the exercises. I greatly appreciate any help. I am just learning on my own.

```
max(x, y)
int x, y;
{
    if (x > y)
        return (x);
    else
        return (y);
}

min(x, y)
int x, y;
{
   if (x < y)
       return (x);
   else
       return (y);  
}

prn_random_numbers(k)   /* print k random numbers */
int k;
{
    int i, r, smallest, biggest;
    int seed;

    srand(seed);
    printf("Please enter a seed: ");
    scanf("%d", &seed);

    r = smallest = biggest = rand();
     printf("\n%12d", r);
    for (i = 1; i < k; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            printf("\n");
        r = rand();
        smallest = min(r, smallest);
        biggest = max(r, biggest);
        printf("%12d", r); 
    }
    printf("\n\n%d random numbers printed.\n", k);
    printf("Minimum:%12d\nMaximum:%12d\n", smallest, biggest);
}

int main() 
{
    int n;

    printf("Some random numbers are to be printed.\n");
    printf("How many would you like to see? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n < 1)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Please enter a positive integer.\n");
        printf("How many would you like to see? ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }        
    prn_random_numbers(n);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Um, you're calling `srand(seed);` before the seed has been entered, with uninitialized data.

Comment: a common way to get a seed to pass into `srand` is to call `time(NULL)`, which will return the current time as a `time_t` value.

Comment: If the question is about "using `srand()` within a function", the answer is almost certainly "don't".  If you use `srand`, you want to use it *once*, usually at the beginning of your program.  So the right place to put it is usually in `main()`.  See also [`srand()` — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Part 1

In the first block of code, you call `srand()` with an uninitialized variable — this is not good.  You need to move that call after where you read the seed from the user.  You should also check that you got a valid result from the input.

```
int main(void) 
{
    int seed;

    printf("Please enter a seed: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &seed) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read seed - exiting\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    srand(seed);
```

#### Part 2

In the second block of code, you are writing K&R-style function definitions.

## DON'T!!!

And yes, I would shout louder if I could.  If your text book is teaching you this style, hurl the book into the rubbish bin and get another book.  You have to have an extraordinary reason to use K&R-style definitions in new code.  Prototypes have been available via standard compilers for about thirty years now, and have been generally available everywhere for twenty years.

Your code calling `srand()` in the second example also has the same flaw as in the first — calling the function before you get a seed from the user.

Also, the chances of users giving a different seed each time the program is run are approximately nil.  Your claim that it "ensures the numbers are random" is a very optimistic view.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful and making that slight adjustment worked! The format I used was something I saw in a short online tutorial. The book was vague on how to use it in this circumstance, so I had no idea. Thank you for taking the time to read my question and respond!